# How do I configure Unity to share an instance in two constructors?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Say I have the following classes / constructors:

```
public class Model {} // Parameterless constructor here
public class Controller { public Controller(Model model) {} }
public class ViewModel { public ViewModel(Model model) {} }
```

I want to have a factory that creates one model, one controller and one viewmodel using the same model instance on the Controller and the ViewModel.

How can I configure Unity to use it on the factory so that the same instance is used in both constructors?

**EDIT:**

Every time I want to create a ViewModel I want to create a Controller and a Model. So 1VM = 1C = 1M and the model is shared between the VM and the C.

Comment: If you really need exactly "one model" you can register it with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` lifetime (singleton)... But it is probably not what you are looking for. Consider adding information on how these objects related to each other if there are more than one `Controller`/`ViewModel` pair created over life of the app (I assume it is something like WPF, not ASP.Net MVC)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: added an edit. The ContainerControlledLifetimeManager won't work this time.

Comment: How are the controller, model and the view model related? In other words, how does the factory know which model and view model to create for the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how your View Model and Control are related, so it's a little hard to see how resolving one will resolve the other.  Something you can try is a factory with two `out` parameters and Injection Constructor.

```
// However you decide to setup your factory method
public static void CreateViewModelAndController(
    out ViewModel viewModel, 
    out Controller controller, 
    IUnityContainer unityContainer)
{
    Model model = unityContainer.Resolve<Model>();
    viewModel = unityContainer.Resolve<ViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(model));
    controller = unityContainer.Resolve<Controller>(new InjectionConstructor(model));
}
```

Comment: InjectionConstructor was the answer. Thanks!